# Find the longest common interval between points on graph

Tags: python, time-series

I am given the following input:

```
[[['3', '7'], ['9', '17']], [['1', '5'], ['10', '20']], [['0', '6'], ['12', '19']]]
```

Each sub-array consists of one or more elements`[['3', '7'], ['9', '17']]` means that this function1 is growing between x = 3 and x = 7, the same function1 is also growing between x=9 and x = 17.
Another function2 is growing between x=1 and x=5, and the same function2 is growing between x=10 and x=20.

This can be seen in a better formatted way here:

```
[['3', '7'], ['9', '17']]
[['1', '5'], ['10', '20']]
[['0', '6'], ['12', '19']]
```

I need to find a way to compute the max growth interval of all the 3 functions together. In this case the solution is from x = 12 to x = 17, because 17-12 = 5 is bigger than any other possible combination.

another solution is x =3 to x =5, but since is not the maximal, this is not the correct solution

Is there a pythonic way to find this?

Until now i tried to compute it for this specific case, without success.

This is the simplest case I am given, and it's only one case out of many. 
My problem is that i can't find the correct way to compare the element of the sublists, in order to get where all the functions are growing in the same interval...

Comment: So you are looking for the longest common interval?

Comment: @EmilVikström Yes that's exactly what i am looking for, but i have no idea on how to write it ...

Comment: are there only integer numbers used in the array? I suppose not, but just checking

Comment: @MarcinCuprjak Yes, there are only integer numbers in the array, at least for now. It will be already fine a working solution just with integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the most concise solution I could come up with (for explanation as to what's going on in here, see below):

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

def get_longest_interval(x):
    longest_interval = max(
        ([v for _, v in grp] for k, grp in groupby(enumerate(
            set.intersection(*(set(chain(*(range(int(start), int(end)+1) for (start, end) in f_intervals))) for f_intervals in x))
        ), lambda (index, num): index-num)), key=len
    )
    return longest_interval[0], longest_interval[-1]

x1 = [[['3', '7'], ['9', '17']],
      [['1', '5'], ['10', '20']],
      [['0', '6'], ['12', '19']]]

x2 = [[[3, 7], [9, 21]],
      [[1, 5], [10, 20]],
      [[0, 6]]]

for x in x1, x2:
    print get_longest_interval(x)

# This prints
(12, 17)
(3, 5)
```

Explanation (all of this becomes a bit more understandable once you create some variables):

```
def get_longest_interval(x):
    # Get available ranges for every function
    function_ranges = [
        set(
            # By chaining and unpacking them so (2 -> 4), (7 -> 9) becomes (2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9)
            chain(*(range(int(start), int(end)+1) for (start, end) in f_intervals))
        ) for f_intervals in x
    ]
    print "Function ranges", function_ranges

    # Get the intersection of all the ranges:
    #   This is the only place where everyone is increasing
    valid_range = set.intersection(*function_ranges)
    print "Valid range", valid_range

    # Use python recipe to get groups of consecutive numbers using groupby
    # https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples
    # (3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17) -> ([3, 4, 5], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
    # Then take the one that contains the most elements (max by length)
    longest_interval = max(
        ([v for _, v in grp] for k, grp in groupby(enumerate(valid_range), lambda (index, num): index-num)), key=len
    )
    return longest_interval[0], longest_interval[-1]

# This prints
Function ranges [set([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]), set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])]
Valid range set([3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
(12, 17)
Function ranges [set([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]), set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]), set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]
Valid range set([3, 4, 5])
(3, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution! I was stuck on this point by many hours, and this is exactly what i wanted! Simple and understandable! Thank you1

Comment: See updated answer for a more pythonic approach, and yea this question took a while to sink in here as well. Thanks!

Comment: i think there is something wrong with this small script, is working in the example, but if a change the input in `[[[3, 7], [9, 21]], [[1, 5], [10, 20]], [[0, 6]]]` the output should be 3, 5, while the actual output is 10, 20. I am trying to understand why

Comment: Take all the time you need! Thank you for the help and for your time! :)

Comment: @BioShock see latest solution (can *almost* be written in one line if you wanted the entire interval, not just the end points). Explanation is also provided in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the following error : ` method_descriptor object argument after * must be a sequence, not generator`, but no idea why

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Man, i was using a different version! Now everything is fine! I
Thank you for all your time and for this beautiful solution

 ~ Federico P.

Answer (score 1):

If there're only integers, you can use something like that (works with any number of functions and intervals):

```
def full(bornes):
    return [k for k in range(bornes[0], bornes[1] + 1)]

li = [[[0, 8], [9, 17]], [[1, 8], [10, 20]], [[0, 8], [12, 19]]]
li2 = []
for function in li:
    li2.append([full(domain) for domain in function])

dict = {}
for function in li2:
    for domain in function:
        for number in domain:
            if not number in dict:
                dict[number] = 1
            else:
                dict[number] += 1

dict = {k:v for k,v in dict.iteritems() if v == len(li2)}

x_longuest = None
x_current = None
current = 0
longuest = 0
for key in dict:
    if key+1 in dict:
        if current == 0:
            x_current = key
        current += 1
    else:
        if current > longuest:
            longuest = current
            x_longuest = x_current
        current = 0

if current > longuest:
    longuest = current
    x_longuest = x_current

print(x_longuest, longuest)
```

The idea is to make a dictionary with the defined domains, then keep only the points where all the functions are defined, then check in the dictionary the longuest chain.

Comment: Thank you for sharing with me your solution! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let me sketch an idea.

First, get a list of all possible combinations.

```
listOfCombinations = list(itertools.product(function1, function2, function3))
```

Second, loop through that list and take the maximum of the lower bounds and the minimum of the upper bounds. Then check if this is the biggest difference you have found so far.

```
for item in listOfCombinations:
    val1 = max(item[0][0], item[1][0], item[2][0])
    val2 = min(item[0][1], item[1][1], item[2][1])
    range = val2 - val1
    if range > maxRange:
        maxRange = range
```

Answer (score 1):

if there are only integers you can also use sets to automatically calculate intersections:

```
array = [[['3', '7'], ['9', '17']], [['1', '5'], ['10', '20']], [['0', '6'], ['12', '19']]]

s1 = None
s2 = None

for f in array:
    f1 = f[0]
    f2 = f[1]
    sf1 = set(xrange(int(f1[0]), int(f1[1])+1))
    sf2 = set(xrange(int(f2[0]), int(f2[1])+1))
    if not s1:
        s1 = sf1
        s2 = sf2
    else:
        s1.intersection_update(sf1)
        s2.intersection_update(sf2)

print s1, s2
```

Comment: This actually gives me back sets, while i need to know where all the 3 functions `[['3', '7'], ['9', '17']]`, `[['1', '5'], ['10', '20']]`,`[['0', '6'], ['12', '19']` are are growing together, and if there are many points with this characteristic, i need to select the bigger one. In my case is from 12 17. Anyway thanks for your time!